# Why isn't WordPress part of Framework Interop Group?

Tags: php, coding-standards

Are there any technical reasons that prevent WP to be part of [Framework Interop Group](http://www.php-fig.org/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, WordPress's maintains backward compatibility (spaghetti), it would not be feasible to adhere to PSR-0 and rename everything, which is somewhat unfortunate for the long-term, with regards to FIG.

That being said it's possible to adopt it for plugins and themes, there is a trac about it here:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21300